# be expected from vs. be expected by

Tags: prepositions

Would you let me know the difference between the following sentences?

> 1. The company’s third loan payment is expected from ABC Bank on Friday.
> 2. The company’s third loan payment is expected by ABC Bank on Friday.
> 3. The third loan payment is expected from the company on Friday.

I think #2 and #3 have almost the same meaning, but I can't understand #1.
I don't know why 'from' is used in #1. #2 and #3 is much more clear than #1.
(Sorry, there is no context, so please make up some contexts for the above sentences.)

Answer (score 1):

Sentence 1 means that ABC bank are providing the money for the company's third loan payment (the payment is expected *from* the bank, therefore the bank has the payment and should be putting it somewhere).

Sentence 2 means that ABC bank is expecting to receive the company's third loan payment (presumably ABC bank either hold the loan or are responsible for making sure that the loan payment arrives with the lender in good time).

Sentence 3 means that the company is expected to provide the third loan payment but does not say to whom they are providing it.  If additional context makes it clear that ABC are expecting to receive the loan payment then sentences 2 and 3 are near-equivalent, yes.

I'm not sure why you've tagged this "ambiguity" though as none of the sentences are ambiguous.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew.
Here is what I was thinking:


"#1. The company's loan payment is expected from ABC Bank.
= ABC Bank is expected to repay the company's loan.

How can a bank 'repay' a loan? A bank CAN 'give' a loan, but CANNOT 'repay' a loan.
Thus, #1 is incorrect.

#3. The loan payment is expected from the company on Friday.
= The company is expected to repay the loan.

A company (which got a loan from a bank) CAN 'repay'a loan.
Thus, #3 is correct."

I just wanted to know what I was missing.
Then, do you mean that you native speakers can say "A bank is expected to repay a loan"?

Comment: @niue Banks borrow all the time, and are expected to repay loans when they do. More usually, banks make payments on behalf of their customers, and when those customers repay loans, ABC bank will send the loan repayment. Thus you can expect a loan repayment from ABC bank.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the number 1 is telling us the third loan's installment to some company is going to be paid on Friday. The second sentence suggests that the third loan's re-payment is being made by some company to the bank on Friday. The third sentence's meaning is similar to the second one, although, to me, it sounds awkward. However, I am not native English speaker, so maybe I am wrong.